# Free SparkSQL ODBC Driver

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, odbc

Is there any free ODBC driver that you could use to connect to the Spark SQL instance? It seems many companies offer the driver but you can either use it with their products only or pay for a license.

I need a driver to connect my service to the local spark cluster. However, I struggle to find one.

Comment: Simba odbc driver for spark, I guess its free.. or Microsoft® Spark ODBC Driver